# Make an enumerable object lazy by default

Tags: ruby, lazy-evaluation, ruby-2.0

I've started playing around with the Enumerable::Lazy functionality in Ruby 2.0 and it looks really useful.

I have an Enumerable collection that pages through a remote data source. Because of this, I would like it to be a "lazy" collection. However, I don't want to have to instruct every user of my class to call .lazy every time they want to use any of the Enumerable methods on it. Instead it would be nice to include a hypothetical LazyEnumerable module and have all the enumerable methods be lazy by default.

Does anyone have any ideas on a clean way to accomplish this? Thanks!

Comment: why not save the enumerable in your class as a lazy enumerable to start with?

Comment: I want the fact that my collection is lazy to be an implementation detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had an idea and thought I would take a stab at this:

```
module LazyEnumerable
  include Enumerable

  def self.make_lazy(*methods)
    methods.each do |method|
      define_method method do |*args, &block|
        lazy.public_send(method, *args, &block)
      end
    end
  end

  make_lazy *(Enumerable.public_instance_methods - [:lazy])
end
```

Curious to know if there is a more robust way to do this.

Comment: The question is what's wrong with your solution? I think this looks good and it won't get any simpler than this.